# rChart gives a blank screen

Tags: r, rcharts

Here is my data:

```
    rawData <- structure(list(Date = c("4/30/2015", "5/1/2015", "5/2/2015", 
"5/3/2015", "5/4/2015", "5/5/2015"), Amount = c(23L, 43L, 32L, 
43L, 43L, 32L)), .Names = c("Date", "Amount"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

The following comes out blank:

```
rPlot(Amount~Date, data = rawData, type = 'bar')
```

I have no idea why -- I'm new to rCharts though -- I usually use ggplot2.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 've seen as many tutorials or blogs as I could find about rCharts and there is no example of `rPlot` being used with a `bar` type anywhere with a data set similar to yours (there is only one [here](http://bl.ocks.org/patilv/raw/7360262/) but it is being used as a histogram with binned variables and counts which is not the same).

The `rPlot` function works fine if you change the `bar` type to `line`, which makes me think that you cannot use `rPlot` in this case.

```
#this works
p1 <- rPlot(x='Date', y='Amount', data = rawData, type = 'line')
p1
```

It seems to me that if you want to plot a barchart the best thing is to use the `vPlot` (or `hPlot` for a horizontal bar) function which works fine:

```
p1 <- vPlot(x='Date', y='Amount', data = rawData, type = 'bar')
p1
```

[image]

And actually as per @Shiva 's message below you can also do (type = 'column' will print it vertically):

```
hPlot(x='Date', y='Amount', data = rawData, type = 'column')
```

Which actually looks even better:

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see. Where are vPlot and hPlot from? They don't seem to be part of the rCharts package..

Comment: Both are from the `rCharts` package. `rCharts` is installed from github and it is not documented properly unfortunately... If you type `vPlot` or `hPlot` on your console, you will see the `<environment: namespace:rCharts>` at the bottom of the source code. `> vPlot
function (x, y, data, type, ...) 
{
    def_spec <- get_def_spec(type)
    vChart <- Vega$new(def_spec)
    params_ <- getLayer(x, y, data, type, ...)
    data_values <- toJSONArray(fixLayerVega(params_)$data, json = F)
    vChart$data_values(data_values)
    return(vChart)
}
<environment: namespace:rCharts>`

Comment: or type `ls(package:rCharts)` on your console which will show all of the functions in the `rCharts` package. Both `vPlot` and `hPlot` are in there.

Comment: You can get vertical bars in hPlot too. Just use `column` in place of `bar`

`hPlot(x='Date', y='Amount', data = rawData, type = 'column')`

Comment: @Shiva Thanks for the comment. Learnt something new today :)

Comment: @LyzandeR I have seen bar plots using rPlot too... I am not sure why it doesn't work here... The following is a working example !
`> data (HairEyeColor)
> hair_eye = as.data.frame(HairEyeColor)
> rPlot(Freq ~ Hair | Eye, color = 'Eye', data = hair_eye, type = 'bar' )`